# Replacing the first occurrence of a value in each row of a pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame like this:

| col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 7 | 12 | 9 |
| 0 | 9 | 9 | 1 |
| 9 | 9 | 1 | 1 |
| 10 | 5 | 2 | 9 |
| 9 | 3 | 0 | 18 |

Each row has at least one 9 and for each row, I want to replace the first instance of it with 90.

Currently, I'm doing:

```py
out = df.mask(df.eq(9) & df.apply(lambda x: ~x.duplicated(), axis=1), 90)
```

Is there any better/faster way than this?

Expected output:

```py
   col1  col2  col3  col4
0     5     7    12    90
1     0    90     9     1
2    90     9     1     1
3    10     5     2    90
4    90     3     0    18
```

Constructor:

```py
data = {'col1': [5, 0, 9, 10, 9],
        'col2': [7, 9, 9, 5, 3],
        'col3': [12, 9, 1, 2, 0],
        'col4': [9, 1, 1, 9, 18]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may check with `numpy` assign

```
df.values[df.index, np.argmax(df.values==9,1)] = 90 
df
Out[56]: 
   col1  col2  col3  col4
0     5     7    12    90
1     0    90     9     1
2    90     9     1     1
3    10     5     2    90
4    90     3     0    18
```

Answer (score 1):

One way using `idxmax`:

```
s = df.eq(9).idxmax(axis=1)
s = s.apply(df.columns.get_loc)
df.values[s.index, s.values] = 90
```

Output:

```
   col1  col2  col3  col4
0     5     7    12    90
1     0    90     9     1
2    90     9     1     1
3    10     5     2    90
4    90     3     0    18
```

This is about 2.5x faster than the original code:

```
%timeit df.mask(df.eq(9) & df.apply(lambda x: ~x.duplicated(), axis=1), 90)
# 2.59 ms ± 80.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%%timeit    
s = df.eq(9).idxmax(axis=1)
s = s.apply(df.columns.get_loc)
df.copy().values[s.index, s.values] = 90 # Note the copy is to keep the df same over the `timeit`

# 1.07 ms ± 31.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way:

```
df.mask(df.eq(9)).T.fillna(90,limit=1).T.fillna(9)
```

Update:

Here is a way using `rank()`

```
df.mask(df.eq(9).rank(axis=1,method='first',ascending=False).eq(1),90)
```

And here is a way using `idxmax()`

```
s = df.set_axis(range(df.shape[1]),axis=1).eq(9).idxmax(axis=1)
df.to_numpy()[range(df.shape[0]),s] = 90
```

or

```
df.mask(df.eq(9).cumsum(axis=1).eq(1) & df.eq(9),90)
```

Output:

```
   col1  col2  col3  col4
0   5.0   7.0  12.0  90.0
1   0.0  90.0   9.0   1.0
2  90.0   9.0   1.0   1.0
3  10.0   5.0   2.0  90.0
4  90.0   3.0   0.0  18.0
```

Comment: I suspect it will be expensive for large dataset, especially the transpose part

Comment: I agree, I was expecting `fillna()` to allow me to set `axis=1` but it appears to ignore the limit

Answer (score 1):

You can use `eq` + `cummax` + `^`:

```
x = df.eq(9).cummax(axis=1)
df[x ^ x.shift(axis=1)] = 90

# One-liner:
df[df.eq(9).cummax(axis=1).pipe(lambda x: x ^ x.shift(axis=1))] = 90
```

Output:

```
>>> df
   col1  col2  col3  col4
0     5     7    12    90
1     0    90     9     1
2    90     9     1     1
3    10     5     2    90
4    90     3     0    18
```